# .on('click') function on jquery not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[image: when I click the list it does not transfer to the input form]

```
$(this).on("click","#l",function(){
                var message = $(this).text();
                alert(message);
                var split = message.split("_");
                $("#lastnamesearch").val(split[0]);
                $("#firstnamesearch").val(split[1]); 
                $(".lastname-list").html('');

            });
```

This is the snippet of the code I am working on. This form searches inside the database using ajax. But the part above does not seem to work. I tried using click(); but it still does not work. `#l` is a dynamically printed list with that id `<a id="l">data</a>`. Can you tell me what is wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#lastnamesearch").keyup(function(){
                var lastname = $(this).val();
                if(lastname != ''){
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'../database/lastnamesearch.php',
                        method:'post',
                        data:{query:lastname},
                        success:function(response){
                            $(".lastname-list").html(response);
                            console.log(response);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    $(".lastname-list").html('');
                }
            });
            $(document).on("click","#l",function(){
                var message = $(this).text();
                alert(message);
                var split = message.split("_");
                $("#lastnamesearch").val(split[0]);
                $("#firstnamesearch").val(split[1]); 
                $(".lastname-list").html('');
               
            });
              $("#lastnamesearch").focus(function(){
                $(".lastname-list").show();
            });

            $("#firstnamesearch").focus(function(){
                $(".firstname-list").show();
            });
            
            $("#lastnamesearch").focusout(function(){
                $(".lastname-list").hide();
            });
            
             $("#firstnamesearch").focusout(function(){
                $(".firstname-list").hide();
            });
            //first name search
            $("#firstnamesearch").keyup(function(){
                var firstname = $(this).val();
                if(firstname != ''){
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'../database/firstnamesearch.php',
                        method:'post',
                        data:{query:firstname},
                        success:function(response){
                            $(".firstname-list").html(response);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    $(".firstname-list").html('');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: *does not seem to work* - what *does* it do?  Do you get the click event?  Have you checked with some basic debugging (eg a console.log inside the event handler)?  Can you provide a *complete* snippet that *demonstrates* the issue?  See [mcve].

Comment: It does not register the click event. When I try to print something inside the event it does not print.

Comment: Hi, can you output of `console.log(response)` ?

Comment: ```<a id='l' class = 'list-group-item list-group-action-border-1' style='z-index:200;margin-top:0px;'>delacruz_boboy</a><a id='l' class = 'list-group-item list-group-action-border-1' style='z-index:200;margin-top:35px;'>sta. ana_paul</a><a id='l' class = 'list-group-item list-group-action-border-1' style='z-index:200;margin-top:70px;'>ferolina_manoy</a>```

Comment: you have same ids for mutliple elements try using class `list-group-item` here `$(document).on("click",".list-group-item",function(){ //your codes ..})` see if that works .

Comment: still does not work

Comment: when you click on your `a` tags does that whole list get hide ? because you have focusout event also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229965/discussion-between-mendrix-manlangit-and-swati).

Comment: You can't have multiple times the same ID. One ID must be unique. Use a class instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use event delegation

```js
// Attach a delegated event handler
$("#list").on("click", "a", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <ul id="list">
    <li><a href="http://domain1.com">Item #1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/local/path/1">Item #2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/local/path/2">Item #3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://domain4.com">Item #4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[jquery document](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: $(document) is also delegation event